# Webpack is not loading Css, Images and font

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack-style-loader, webpack-5

I am trying to load the Css, Images and fonts using the webpack. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist")
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "restaurant-page",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

This is my index.js. When I uncomment the `./styles.css` import I get the
`main.js:290 Uncaught Error: Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser` in chrome console and my js imports doesn't work but it dosen't throw me error while building project  when I run `npm run build` commmand in terminal. I tried using css import in each js module-- in home.js etc--file but that also doesn't work.

```
// import './style.css';

import { homeContent, removeIntroContent } from './Modules/home.js';
import { aboutContent, removeAboutContent } from './Modules/about.js';
import { reviewsContent, removeReviewContent } from './Modules/reviews.js';



const home = document.getElementById("home-btn");
const review = document.getElementById("review-btn");
const about = document.getElementById("about-btn");

homeContent();

home.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    removeReviewContent();
    removeAboutContent();
    const id = document.getElementById("intro-content");
    if(id != null) return;
    homeContent();
});

review.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    removeAboutContent();
    removeIntroContent();
    const id = document.getElementById("reviews");
    if(id != null) return;
    reviewsContent();
});

about.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    removeReviewContent();
    removeIntroContent();
    const id = document.getElementById("about");
    if(id != null) return;
    aboutContent()
});
```

I have pushed the code to github if anyone want to look at file structure
Here is the [link](https://github.com/MubashirWaheed/Restaurant-Page)

ps: If I use the link tag to add css to html it works exactly as I want it to but that defeats the purpose of using webpack

Comment: The error message indicates that you should set `publicPath` in you webpack config at `output`

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning to set publicPath as I am not working with servers and publicPath has something to do with servers (Not 100% sure as I am still very new to this). But anyway I tried `publicPath: path.resolve("/public/assets/js")`it did removed the error but my images and font from css are not loading. As i mentioned in my other comment the issue is the loading of images and font and not with css which I initially thought was.

Comment: `as I am not working with servers` you always have a server, where else should the browser load the files from? `publicPath` is used to tell the loader where to find the resource. It is not the local path in the filesystem, but the portion after the domain in  the URL that points to your output directory (`path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist")`). So it might be something like `publicPath: '/dist'`.

Answer (score -1):

I am having trouble with Webpack as well and I came across your question. I don't have a sure solution to your problem, but I hope to steer you in the right direction.

At first glance, I am wondering if editing your package.json file to use your webpack-config when you run 'npm run build' instead of the default webpack config. This could help activate the loaders you are trying to use, or atleast populate error messages that would allow you to investigate further. Editing your package.json would look like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack-config.js"
}
```

Your dependencies make sense and your file path for style.css seems correct, so I am wondering if Webpack does not know how to load your styles, fonts, images without your config file.

Can read more about Webpack configuration here.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Hope I was able to help, good luck! If you have any further questions I'd be happy to help, as I'm learning Webpack too.

Comment: Yesterday I tried debugging it myself. I identified the source of error. Style loader and css loaders aren't the issue here. My css file has images and font if I comment out these two items in my css everything else loads perfectly fine. So the issue is the way I am loading images and font.  
I tried `"build": "webpack --config ./webpack-config.js"`  but in gave me the error `Error: Cannot find module '/home/mubashir/Documents/Restaurant-Page/webpack-config.js'` probably because there is hypen in `./webpack-config.js` so after consulting webpack I used period in place of hyphen.

Comment: It compiled without errors but my issue wasn't solved (I was still getting the error)